Does "absorb back" or "circulate back" work?
I want to form a cycle. That's why I want to use the word "back". But I'm not sure if any of the bold expressions works.

Overall, ethanol production is a cyclical process that consists of
harvesting plants, extracting cellulose, converting it into sugars,
adding microbes to create ethanol, and plants absorbing back
carbon dioxide produced when ethanol is burned.


Overall, ethanol production is a cyclical process that consists of harvesting plants, extracting cellulose, converting it into sugars, adding microbes to create ethanol, and carbon dioxide produced when ethanol is burned circulating
back to plants.

I wrote them.


Overall, ethanol production is a cyclical process that consists of harvesting plants, extracting cellulose, converting it into sugars, adding microbes to create ethanol which, when burned, produces carbon dioxide that plants (again) absorb (during photosynthesis).

@RonaldSole, you thank but I want to form a cycle.

I ought to say first that improving prose is not a service that is offered on this site. However, I think that my example already forms a cycle. If you wanted to emphasise this, you could start by including a phrase such as: "....consists of harvesting plants, which absorb carbon dioxide (by photosynthesis), extracting cellulose, converting it into ...etc.. And modify the ending to avoid repetition.

Since the plants that produced the cellulose were harvested, it would be other plants that absorb the carbon dioxide produced when  the ethanol is burned. So "plants absorbing back" should be teased out a bit. The carbon dioxide absorption doesn't replenish the plant world at the same rate as the harvesting depletes it, does it?

The inclusion of the word "back" suggests a reversal of a process. For example, you might "take back" something that you already "took" somewhere. So, "absorbing back carbon dioxide" suggests that the plants previously expelled it.
The simplistic view of the respiration and photosynthesis cycle is that humans and plants breathe O2 and expel CO2, while plants reverse that process. In fact, plants expel CO2 too, mainly at night, because photosynthesis requires sunlight. So, it isn't strictly incorrect to say that plants might absorb back some of what they previously expelled, but I don't think that is what is meant.
The graphic portrays an entire cyclical process that begins with plants expelling O2 and then ends with them starting over. So, "absorbing back" helps show that this is the end of the process and the beginning of the cycle all over again.
'Circulating back' is pretty good too, and arguably makes it a bit clearer that this is the end point of a cycle.
I should add though that these terms describe the model. In practice, the gases are unlikely to circulate 'back' to the plants they originated from. True, the "water cycle" is described in similar terms, but in that model, water is shown to cycle between different states rather than cycling back to a place.

Thanks for your answer. Your last sentence uses "cycling back to". Does it mean I can use it as well? ....., and carbon dioxide produced when the ethanol is burned cycling back to plants.

@newbieforever That was completely subconscious - but yes, it might even be the best option because then you're definitely referring to the whole cycle.
